# How do I get a bash script file to request a prompt before continuing to the next step?

Tags: bash

I have a one line script to create a file in a directory and open the file with Kwrite. I'd like the script to prompt for the file name to be created and to be opened by Kwrite. At present it doesn't even open the terminal but ideally it should. How do I achieve this with the following script?:

`cat > file.php & kwrite file.php`

My intention is to paste copied portions of one file to create a new file.

Comment: Better ask about what you want to achieve, rather than about help with a method you *think* will allow you to achieve your goal. For what you try here, you do not need a script. A simple `kwrite filename` will immediately open kwrite and have that save to `filename`.

Comment: @vanadium what you say makes much sense. I'm converting some html layouts to WordPress php templates and am trying to reduce some repetition. A WP page comprises several included blocks. Each block of html markup needs to be integrated with some php. After I copy the block I want to make a php file without having to have multiple screens and applications. I open a new php file with. `printf '<?php get-header()?>\n\n<?php get-footer()?>' > foo.php & kwrite foo.php` works but I want to be prompted to name each new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1: Using a bash script parameter**

Create the script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
( echo something > "$1".php && kwrite "$1".php ) &
clear
```

Then, you can call the script passing the file name after the command. The script will then automatically create the file with the content you wish, adding the `.php` extension automatically, and open the file in kwrite, while releasing the terminal prompt for you to enter a following command.

`$1` in the script is a variable that automatically retrieves the next word on the command line. e.g. if the script is called `phpfile`, then the command

```
phpfile myfile
```

will create and open the file `myfile.php`.

**Option 2. Using the `read` command**

The `read` command allows to prompt the user for input at the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter filename: "
read FILENAME
echo something > "$FILENAME".php && nohup kwrite "$FILENAME".php &
clear
```

`nohup` may be useful if you are working from the terminal. It detaches the editor from the terminal processes, so it will not be closed if you close the terminal.

**Option 3. Using a graphical tool**

**Zenity**, installed by default in Ubuntu, or **Kdialog** on the Plasma desktop, allow you to prompt the user for input in a graphical dialog for use in scripts. You invoke these tools in a script. The user input then is placed in a variable. Advantage here is that then you could assign the script to a shortcut key. Then you could summon it with a single keypress to have the Zenity dialog pop up and have the script do its work.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME=$(zenity --entry --title "Name request" --text "Please enter file name:")
echo something > "$FILENAME".php && nohup kwrite "$FILENAME".php &
clear
```

Comment: Thanks @vanadium. You set me on the path to the solution with the tokenization. Your answer creates the empty file(s). This script prompts for a name: `#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter filename"
read filename
printf '<?php get_header()?>\n\n<?php get_footer()?>' > "$filename".php & kwrite "$filename".php` . My issue now is to execute the script via a double click. I'll install Zenity presently because it sounds from what you said exactly the solution.

Comment: Indeed, zenity will probably be what you are looking for. For completeness, I added also the "read" option (input on the terminal), and I added examples for all the options. M

Comment: your recommendation of Zenity led me to Kdialog and opened up a whole new aspect to my script that has grown from seven lines to 27 with a radio list box that opens up options for the user (me). It also made error handling easier for a novice. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is useful for you: mark the checkbox next to the question. I have also made reference to Kdialog for Plasma users in my answer.

Comment: Done! Thought I had already accepted it but seems I had only up voted. Good that you added Kdialog as it's installed with KDE. I've even done a README.md now that this looks so nifty.